# QT batch file not executing.

Tags: c++, windows, qt, shell, batch-file

I have a multi-line batch file created using the following:

```
QFile file("C:/temp_exec.bat");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream out(&file);
out << cmd;
out << "\n";
out << cmd_alt;
file.close();
```

Where cmd and cmd_alts are legitimate multi-line batch commands. The created file executes fine with double click inside Windows, but through QT, it never executes.

I've tried literally all that there's available, and this was my latest attempt,

```
QProcess p;
p.setWorkingDirectory("C:/");
p.execute("temp_exec.bat");
p.waitForFinished();
```

Which works fine under the Qt Creator, but in a standalone executable (inside a folder with all the required Qt DLL's), nothing happens. CMD shell just opens and closes like nothing's happened.

Here's what's created inside temp_exec.bat:

```
cd /d "Z:\FRONT 2" & for %%i in (*) do move /Y "%%i" "Z:\2005\050016"
cd /d "Z:\FRONT 2" & for /d %%i in (*) do ROBOCOPY /E /IS /MOVE "%%i" "Z:\2005\050016"
```

Which If double click and run inside Windows it's OKAY, but through Qt, it's NOT.

I don't get why the framework doesn't explain WHY through QProcess STRANGE things happen.

Any ideas? Help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

nvm solved it. Used `p.startDetached()`